Rotary switch configuration
I have 6 power supplies that I need to select in 3 groups. Each of these 6 outputs will go to a different pin based on the group selected:

Let’s call them group A, B, & C.
And power supply 1-6.
Power supplies 1-6 will be adjustable from 0-20A and 0-7.5V

I would like to use a rotary switch to accomplish this:

When I select group A,I need outputs from Power supply 1-6 to go to pins A-F.
When I select group B, I need power supply 1-6 outputs to go to pins G-L.
when I select group C, I need Power supply outputs 1-6 to go to pins M-Q.

I am struggling trying to figure out how I would configure this and what rotary switch I would need and how to wire it.

How much current is the switch going to be to carrying between the supplies and the their loads? And what are the supply voltages?

how would you do it with one power supply? ... repeat six times
